# How to use parallelization properly in C++ to make the code faster?

Tags: c++

I am trying to use parallelization in C++.

Below is just a sample code I wrote.

I heard that I need enough amount of N in order to make parallelization work.(In this code 'i' I guess...)

So I came up with 3-dimensional arrays. (I increase the size of 'Stack Reserve Size' to run the code below.)

And I used 'chrono' to measure elapsed time.

But in this code, parallelization actually makes code slower.

So I was wondering what could be the reason in this case.

Is this because the fixed cost of running parallelization is still large compared to the number of 'i' I have here?

```
int main() {
    omp_set_num_threads(8);
    double AAA[1000][1000][10];
    double A[1000];
    fill(&AAA[0][0][0], &AAA[0][0][0] + sizeof(AAA) / sizeof(AAA[0][0][0]), 1);
    fill(&A[0], &A[0] + sizeof(A) / sizeof(AAA[0]), 2);

    system_clock::time_point start = system_clock::now();
    #pragma omp parallel for private(A)
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
                AAA[i][j][k] = A[i] + A[j] + A[k];
            }
        }
    }
    system_clock::time_point end = system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> sec = end - start;
    cout << sec.count() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is *memory-bound*.
This means that the program spends much more time moving data to/from memory/caches than actually computing.
Indeed, the computation consists only in two additions.
You could increase your arrays (on the heap, not in the stack of course), the ratio between memory transfer and computation time would be the same or even worse (as data do not fit entirely in cache).
From the point of view of the processor, having eight cores waiting for memory transfers (write buffers) does not help more than having only one core waiting (except if you have distinct memory controllers and a good balance of the physical memory usage on a NUMA system for example).

If you want to observe a gain with parallelisation, you need to increase the amount of computation performed with the same amount of data.
Below is your example modified in a very stupid way, just in order to observe this gain (4.365 to 0.652153 seconds on my system).

```
/**
  g++ -std=c++17 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -O3 -march=native -fopenmp
**/

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>

int
main()
{
  constexpr auto ni=2000, nj=ni, nk=100;
  auto AAA=std::vector<double>(ni*nj*nk, 1.0);
  auto A=std::vector<double>(ni, 2.0);

#if defined _OPENMP
  omp_set_num_threads(8);
#endif
  const auto start=std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(auto i=0; i<ni; ++i)
  {
    for(auto j=0; j<nj; ++j)
    {
      for(auto k=0; k<nk; ++k)
      {
        const auto idx=i*(nj*nk)+j*nk+k;
        if(j<k)
        {
          AAA[idx]+=std::sqrt(A[i])+std::log(A[j]);
        }
        else
        {
          AAA[idx]+=std::log(A[j])+std::cos(A[k]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  const auto end=std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  const auto duration=std::chrono::duration<double>{end-start};
  std::cout << duration.count() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think this is a stupid question but is there a problem if I just increase the size of stack and save every carry in stack instead of heap? If I use stack instead of heap, is parallelization not going to work?

Comment: And I have changed your example with ni = 1000, and nk = 100. When I use 'release', it seems like the results are the same with '#pragma omp parallel for' and without '#pragma omp parallel for'. 0.37 seconds. However, if I use 'debug' I see some differences between the two results. So I was wondering if parallelization only works in debug?

Comment: @ChangseokMa Stack space is usually very limited (kilo-bytes to a few mega-bytes, depending on the system), so, in order to avoid crashes due to stack-overflow ;^) we usually allocate large amounts of data in the heap (whatever the problem, parallelisation or not). This will not change anything about parallelisation.

Comment: @ChangseokMa About the debug/release concern on your system, I have no clue... On my system I tested with optimisations turned on (see the command line); perhaps your compiler is very smart at optimising the `if` and the maths calls so that the parallelisation has no measurable effect after these optimisations?

Comment: Thank you. I have an additional question..... If I use ni = 2000, nk =100 as you uploaded. Somehow my C++ doesn't work so that I need to decrease the size to ni = 1000 and nk = 10. As far as I know, vector<double> doesn't need dynamic allocation right.....? Then is this just an issue of my computer memory??

Comment: @ChangseokMa yes `std::vector<>` uses heap allocation, that's why I used it here, in order to create a large array without worrying about the stack. 2000*2000*100 `double`s represents approximately 3GB of memory.

Comment: @prof-fh: Thank you so much now I can see how parallelization can speed up the C++ code. I just want to ask you about the memory-bound to understand this correctly. "program spends much more time moving data to/from memory/caches than actually computing" I actually don't get the 'moving data' part. Why is data moving if I use parallelization? Can I just understand this as 'To make parallelization works, either the size of the array should be large or computation should be complicated so that the advantage from parallelization is greater than the fixed cost of using parallelization'

Comment: @ChangseokMa [this link](https://www.igi-global.com/dictionary/memory-bound/18281) might help. Memory-bound vs compute-bound is not specific to parallelisation but parallelisation does not help much for memory-bound problems. I think one should understand computer architecture in general before leaning towards parallelisation since it cannot magically increase performances just by itself, without any other consideration.